# Detect virtual keyboard on screen and landscape orientation in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

Am working on a html based mobile app where there is requirement to design app only for portrait orientation and display message to user when he goes to landscape, This feature is working fine with css media query but problem is this that I have a form in app and when I click on any of the textbox and virtual keyboard opens and screen height changes and it shows me message for orientation change

Now I want to ask if there any way to different when actually orientation changes and when virtual keyboard on screen appears.
Thanks in advance

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {

}
```

I have checked other questions related to my topic on stackoverflow but nothing helpful there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The short answer:

No, unfortunately there is no current way to detect when the virtual keyboard appears on screen. Detecting orientation yes, that's possible using:

1. css media queries (*as per you example*)
2. via JavaScript using the `orientationchange` listener.
3. via JavaScript using the `resize` listener and inferring the orientation using `window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth`

#### The long answer:

There should be no reason why the keyboard affects the `orientation` property that is interpreted by your css media query as follows:

```css
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    ...
}
```

The W3C [media queries recomendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation) states the following for the `orientation` property:

> The ‘orientation’ media feature is ‘portrait’ when the value of the ‘height’ media feature is greater than or equal to the value of the ‘width’ media feature. Otherwise ‘orientation’ is ‘landscape’.

The keyboard being visible when you type in the forms textbox field simply should not trigger the `orientation` property to change.

I have in the past had your issue occur when using device emulators, such as Device Mode in older versions of Google Chrome's devtools. However, when it was tested on real mobile device/s the issue did not occur.

Also, there is this [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=490618) open in mobile chrome that may be causing resize events to fire when the keyboard appears.

Perhaps the emulator, if that's what you are using, is incorrectly causing the the viewports height to change therefore causing the change to the `orientation`property in your media query.

The simple gist I provided below does the following (*You could try running it in your dev environment to see what happens*):

1. When the mobile device is in portrait orientation the screen shows two form input fields (displaying the words: 'foo' and 'baz').
2. When I touch either of the form input fields the keyboard is displayed and there is no change to the content of the page.
3. When the device it rotated 90 degrees to landscape orientation a gray panel appears showing the words: "Rotate your device to portrait"

**NOTE:**  The steps listed above are what happens when testing the gist below on several real mobile devices running Safari on iOS and mobile Chrome on Android (...not emulators!).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>StackOveflow question 40175207</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Example gist using orientation css media query to hsow message when device is landscape" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<style type="text/css">

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.message-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: gray;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
            transform: translateX(100%);

    will-change: transform;
}

.message-panel__text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font: 1em Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    .message-panel {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="input-one" value="foo">
            <input type="text" name="input-two" value="baz">
        </form>
        <div class="message-panel">
            <div class="message-panel__text">Rotate your device to portrait</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: There is also Web App Manifest in Chrome for Android which allows you to lock the orientation of the device too. See [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-installable-web-apps-with-webapp-manifest-in-chrome-38-for-Android) for further info.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

You can't detect whether there is or is not the virtual keyboard only using CSS. You'll need to use some javascript.

If you are using Cordova to build the app, try using the Keyboard plugin. It fires an event whenever keyboard is shown or hidden, so that you can respond to it somehow, ie. add some class to `<body>` that will prevent showing the message.

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard

Another approach would be to listen to "focus" event on all possible elements that can cause the keyboard to appear.

```
$(document.body).on("focus", "textarea, input", function() {
   $(document.body).addClass("do-not-show-message");
}).on("blur", "textarea, input", function() {
   $(document.body).removeClass("do-not-show-message");
});;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can detect focus on input.
It is very likely that the device will show a virtual keyboard in the mobile version of your application. To find out, you can compare the height of some element. For example, the application was 800 pixels high, nothing changed (there was no screen flip), but the height changed and now it is 500 pixels. And also you know that the focus is on the input field. This may mean that a virtual keyboard has appeared on the screen. Or not in some cases :)

Comment: So basically your solution works sometimes and sometimes doesn't?

Comment: Right. I think it will work 90 percent, and maybe more.

Answer (score 2):

I had troubles designing a chat view in HTML. Header at top, content center and chat field at the bottom. In the end, this was the solution I opted for

- Flexbox for the layout
- Height of the flexbox set to 100vh.
- Because 100vh is problematic in Safari, detect Safari with js and set to 100%

Here's a fiddle that shows my solution

```js
var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
if (isSafari) {
  document.body.className = "is-safari";
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.chat {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: white;
}
.is-safari .chat {
  height: 100%;
}
.chat__header,
.chat__footer {
  background: whitesmoke;
  height: 60px;
}
.chat__body {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Chat View</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="chat">
    <div class="chat__header">Header</div>
    <div class="chat__body">Body</div>
    <div class="chat__footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following to detect the virtual keyboard being displayed. I assume 2 things:

1. The keyboard height is more than 50px, which helps ignore someone resizing a screen manually.
2. The width doesn't change when the keyboard is displayed. This avoids catching someone rotating their screen.

Basically, when the page loads, it saves the height and width. You can do extra checks here to make sure the page isn't loaded in landscape. After that, any resize event runs a check. Did the height go down by 50px or more, while the width stayed the same? If so: keyboard was likely shown! If the height goes up by more than 50px while the width stays the same, the keyboard was hidden.

```
window.onload = WindowOnload;
window.onresize = WindowResize;

function WindowOnload() {
    document.body.setAttribute("height", window.innerHeight);
    document.body.setAttribute("width", window.innerWidth);
    if(window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth) { /* Page loaded in landscape */ }
}

function WindowResize() {
    const previousWidth = parseInt(document.body.getAttribute("width"));
    const newWidth = window.innerWidth;
    const previousHeight = parseInt(document.body.getAttribute("height"));
    const newHeight = window.innerHeight;

    if(previousWidth === newWidth) {
        if(previousHeight > newHeight+50) { /* Keyboard was displayed */ console.log("shown"); }
        else if (previousHeight+50 < newHeight) { /* Keyboard was hidden */ console.log("hidden"); }
    }

    document.body.setAttribute("height", window.innerHeight);
    document.body.setAttribute("width", window.innerWidth);
}
```